# При изменении размера страницы содержимое съезжает стороны HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

[image: До и после изменения размера страницы]

Что добавить в код CSS, чтобы содержимое не разъезжалось в стороны при уменьшении размера страницы зажатием Ctrl + колесо прокрутки?
У логотипа float: left, у меню и ссылки авторизации float: right.

Answer (score 1):

Добавить надо в разметку - контейнер-обёртку для содержимого. И задать ему `max-width: 1170px` (на самом деле любую ширину, в зависимости от требований в макете). А для выравнивания по центру - `margin: 0 auto`

Тогда при увеличении масштаба содержимое останется в пределах контейнера и не будет разъезжаться по краям экрана.